Displaying taxonomy name in single post template of cpt
I'll start by saying that I have no background in php.
I need to embed a shortcode to display the name of the specific taxonomy the post is associated with.
The shortcode is embedded in a single post template.
Remarks:

I don't need a link to the taxonomy.
how can i embedded it as a shortcode?

I would appreciate your help

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/: "Every shortcode callback is passed three parameters by default, including an array of attributes ($atts), the shortcode content or null if not set ($content), and finally the shortcode tag itself ($shortcode_tag), in that order." - you are currently invoking the get_the_terms directly, with those mentioned parameters - which make no sense whatsoever, for that function. You need to wrap your own code into a custom function, and then specify that function as the callback function.

If you want show only one taxonomy you can try this following version of code.
function display_post_single_tax_terms( $atts ) {
    // Get post ID
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    // Check if post ID exists
    if ( $post_id ) {
        // Get taxonomy terms associated with the post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'your_taxonomy_name' ); // Replace 'your_taxonomy_name' with the name of your taxonomy

        // Check if terms exist
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            return $terms[0]->name; // you can wrap this with any tag if you want;
        }
    }

    return ''; // Return empty string if no taxonomy terms found
}
add_shortcode( 'display_post_taxonomy', 'display_post_single_tax_terms' );


Please try the following code to fetch all the taxonomies associated with post.
make sure you're receiving the proper post ID and correct taxonomy name, so you may need a little bit of debugging, please let me know if you're facing any issues. I'll be happy to help further.
function display_post_taxonomy_terms( $atts ) {
    // Get post ID
    $post_id = get_the_ID();

    // Check if post ID exists
    if ( $post_id ) {
        // Get taxonomy terms associated with the post
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'your_taxonomy_name' ); // Replace 'your_taxonomy_name' with the name of your taxonomy

        // Check if terms exist
        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $taxonomy_list = '<ul>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $taxonomy_list .= '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</a></li>';
            }
            $taxonomy_list .= '</ul>';

            return $taxonomy_list;
        }
    }

    return ''; // Return empty string if no taxonomy terms found
}
add_shortcode( 'display_post_taxonomy', 'display_post_taxonomy_terms' );


Well, do you want to get only one category name without the link?

Thank you very much! This seems to give me the required answer, except for minor changes I had to make to the code. In order for the name of the taxonomy to be displayed without a link and not in a list view, I made the changes I attached in the answer below. It seems to work as it should, I hope I deleted only what needed to be deleted and nothing more than that, and also that I didn't leave anything unnecessary in the code following the deletion.

Yes, only for one category. Because in the case of this specific taxonomy I only assigned each post to one category (taxonomy).
